# How to download Cloud Firestore database collection into a JSON or CSV file?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, electron

Okay so here is the thing, I have been working on a Flutter/Firebase project for a while and now my client is wondering if there's any chance of getting a CSV o JSON file from a certain collection of the Cloud Firestore database for later on being processed by Power Bi or some other data analysis tool.

For being more clear, I have been thinking about building a simple ElectronJS desktop app with Firebase on it, with a simple interface that can be suitable for my client to click few things a get a file with selected collections/documents from the Cloud Firestore database.

I have investigated but the only result that kind of works is using the Export/Import tool of Google Cloud Console, but it is a real headache for someone who's not familiarized with the Google Cloud environment, besides it is not a suitable choice for the client, considering he needs a simple and efficient UI/UX design for interacting with.

If you need more info just comment or write to me directly benjamin.caceres.ra@gmail.com
Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no provided tooling to get a formatted export of Firestore data.  You're going to have to write code to query the database, iterate the documents, and write the output in the format you want.